# Grafana showing no data points when variable filter set to "All"

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am using grafana v5.4.0 with Prometheus as a data source to monitor my application's API calls.

I have created "**Request Count**" (spring-boot graph) and configured 2 of my applications to monitor API's.

In **Graph Setting --> variable --> type = Custom --> Added 2 application names**, also I checked "Include all options" checkbox

But when on the graph I select "**All**", I get no data points

my metric query is as follows,

**irate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="$application"}[5m])**

But when I select individual application name from a variable filter, It shows proper data only when I select "**All**" the message comes "**No data point"**

Can anyone suggest some solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I ran into a similar issue, and I found out that using variables makes grafana add extra escape characters into the label strings.

When inspecting the PromSQL query I found out that extra *%5C* were added to special characters for example.

There is a way to ignore them in the query without modifying the variables, as @Devendra mentioned in his comment:

You need to replace

```
your_metric_name{labelname="$variable_name"}
```

by

```
your_metric_name{labelname=~"$variable_name"}
```

The tilde will make sure that the PromSQL query ignores escape characters.